# how to send msg to Websphere MQ with specific reply to MQ MGR using JMS

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I need to build a java standalone application with ability to send messages to MQSeries specifying reply-to queue and reply-to MQMgr.
I was able to use the code in SimpleP2P example to send a message, but unable to specify the reply-to queue and reply-to MQMgr

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();


        cf.setHostName("xyz.com");
        cf.setPort(141600);
        cf.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
        cf.setQueueManager("QMG");
        cf.setChannel("CHANNEL");


        MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///A.QUEUE");
        MQQueueSender sender = (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);

        long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        String fileText = convertXMLFileToString("test.xml");
        System.out.println("fileText " + fileText);

        JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage(fileText);


        connection.start();

        System.out.println("before Sent message:\\n" + message);

        sender.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

        sender.close();

        session.close();
        connection.close();

        System.out.println("\\nSUCCESS\\n");
    } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
        System.out.println(jmsex);
        System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: i am also trying to send xml file to one queue.but i don't have all dependencies jar file so can you please mention the jar required to run the above program.if possible mentioned the maven dependencies here.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
MQQueue replyToQ = new MQQueue(QMgrName, ReplyQueue);
Destination replyTo = (Destination) replyToQ;
message.setJMSReplyTo(replyTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void postMessageToDatastage(String msg,String queueName,String batchID){

    int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT; 
    try {
        defaultLocalQueue = qManager.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);            
        MQMessage putMessage = new MQMessage();
        putMessage.writeUTF(msg);            
        //specify the message options...
        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); 
        // accept 
        // put the message on the queue
        defaultLocalQueue.put(putMessage, pmo);            
        System.out.println("Message is put on MQ.");
        //System.out.println("Queue is closing...");
         defaultLocalQueue.close();
         // for asynchornus communtication...
        //MQAsyncStatus asyncStatus = qManager.getAsyncStatus();
          qManager.disconnect();

    } catch (MQException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

public void init(){

```
    //Set MQ connection credentials to MQ Envorinment.
     MQEnvironment.hostname = hostName;
     MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
     MQEnvironment.port = port;
     MQEnvironment.userID = user;
     MQEnvironment.password = password;
     //set transport properties.
     MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);

     try {
         //initialize MQ manager.
        qManager = new MQQueueManager(qMngrStr);
    } catch (MQException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```